# Munin plugin for Camel JMX monitoring

Tags: java, apache-camel, munin

Do we have any custom plugins for monitoring routes, processors,components of Camel? I have configured Munin in one of the nodes and enabled JMX monitor plugin to capture the stats of my Java app which used Camel for routing. I could capture the standard JVM stats using jmx_MultigraphAll. Unable to locate a plugin to capture Camel parameters. Do we need to write a custom plugin?

PS: I am able to view the MBeans in JConsole though. How do I get my Munin node to capture the values?

Comment: Try [hawtio](http://hawt.io/plugins/camel/) to monitor Camel routes if you wish to visually see the information. If you wish to monitor Camel, systematically then JMX is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is no camel-minin component for easy integration between the two of them. However as you say Camel exposes a lot of information as JMX as both attributes, and operations you can use.

If munin can integrate with JMX then you can use that to monitor your Camel applications.